# ASP.NET MVC C# Web App - Filtering / Search from DB getting ERROR

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a basic asp.net mvc web application. Its connected with my DB which has many records. I need for it to have a Filter option on the top of the page and a search text box whcih searches for Name. The filter box should be a drop down with all the column names and which ever option is selected, all records pertaining to that option display on the main index page. I have tried to do it but its giving me errors. I hvae attached the following: DataFormsController (index method), the index html page, and the .models page AS WELL as the error i get when I run the application.

If anyone can help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!!!

RiskApplication.models code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace RiskApplication.Models
{
     public class RiskApplicationModel
     {
            public List<DataForm> dataForms;
            public SelectList owners;
            public string department { get; set; }

      }
}
```

index.cshtml:

```
    @model IEnumerable<RiskApplication.Models.DataForm>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>RiskPrescreen Application 2018</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<form asp-controller="DataForms" asp-action="Index" method="get">
    <p>
        <select asp-for="department" asp-items="Model.owners">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>

        Application Name: <input type="text" name="SearchString">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
</form>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        @*<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Application_Exec)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SME)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Project_Directory_Location)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IRDR_name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Risk_Statement)
        </th>*@
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.InherentRisk)
        </th>
        @*<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AppOwner_DD.AppOwnerDes)
        </th>
        <th>*@
         @* @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.C1_DD.C1)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.C2_DD.C2)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.C3_DD.C3)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.C4_DD.C4_des)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.C5_DD.C5)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.C6_DD.C6)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SDLC_Stage_DD.SDLC_Stage)
        </th>*@
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        @*<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Application_Exec)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SME)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Directory_Location)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IRDR_name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Risk_Statement)
        </td>*@
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InherentRisk)
        </td>
        @*<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AppOwner_DD.AppOwnerDes)
        </td>
```

DataFormsController.cs:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string department, string searchString)
    {
        // Use LINQ to get list of genres.
        IQueryable<string> genreQuery = from m in db.AppOwner_DD
                                        orderby m.AppOwnerDes
                                        select m.AppOwnerDes;

        var dataForms = from m in db.DataForms
                        select m;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            dataForms = dataForms.Where(s => s.Name.Contains(searchString));
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(department))
        {
            dataForms = dataForms.Where(x => x.AppOwner_DD.AppOwnerDes == department);
        }

        var movieGenreVM = new RiskApplicationModel();
        movieGenreVM.owners = new SelectList(await genreQuery.Distinct().ToListAsync());
        movieGenreVM.dataForms = await dataForms.ToListAsync();

        return View(movieGenreVM);
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCDUS.png)

Comment: What's the error you are getting? How about sharing the code here in the question itself instead of attachments?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya just shared the code. Let me know if your able to see it

Comment: Also attached the error I get in an image

Comment: The view expects a model of type `IEnumerable<RiskApplication.Models.DataForm>` but you are sending single object of `RiskApplicationModel` to the view. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Hmmm, where exactly shall i insert this? Bit confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aadil,

You are passing a type RiskApplicationModel to the Index view from the Index controller
However the Index view expects a model of type IEnumerable based on the first line in the cshtml  @model IEnumerable

So there is the mismatch between what's sent to the view compared to what the view expects

This needs to be fixed either in the controller or in the view. 
The controller needs to send a type that the view expects or the view should bind itself to a type that the controller is sending.

Or alternatively, the controller could populate a viewmodel and view could be bound to a viewmodel like in the MVVM design pattern (Model-View-ViewModel)

Hope this helps